# homemade jquery youtube gallery wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

i have tried using .toggle instead of .slidetoggle in case this was the problem #v1 is set to display:none; so it doesnt show up until i want it too i have no idea where i have went wrong please any advice is welcome and appreciated.

```
window.onload;
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (true) {
    $('#v1').add('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v0DJNsqVUPI?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    $('#v1').toggle().delay( 2000 );
    $('#v1').slidetoggle().empty();
  }
});
```

there is my javascript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CG Hartlepool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="offersbar">
      Offers bar
    </div>
    <div id="ebayfeed">
      ebay feed
    </div>
    <div id="utube">
      <div id="v1" class="fill"></div>
      <img class="fill" id="img1" src="images/buybacklaptop.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img2" src="images/cashforgold.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img3" src="images/holdittablet.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img4" src="images/buyitback.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img5" src="images/chequecashing.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img6" src="images/sellitxbox.jpg"/>
      <div id="v2" class="fill"></div>
      <img class="fill" id="img7" src="images/buybacktablet.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img8" src="images/cashgold.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img9" src="images/tradeconsole.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img10" src="images/buyitbacklaptop.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img11" src="images/holdit.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img12" src="images/buyconsole.jpg"/>
      <div id="v3" class"fill"></div>
      <img class="fill" id="img13" src="images/holditguitar.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img14" src="images/buyitlaptop.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img15" src="images/selltablet.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img16" src="images/spreadcostguitar.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img17" src="images/cashgoldsilver.jpg"/>
      <img class="fill" id="img18" src="images/travelmoney.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="news">
      news
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my html and below is my css

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2F3646;
}
#offersbar{
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#ebayfeed{
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#utube{
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#fill{
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#news{
  top: 90%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#v1{
  display: none;
}
#v2{
  display: none;
}
#v3{
  display: none;
}
#img1{
  display: none;
}
#img2{
  display: none;
}
#img3{
  display: none;
}
#img4{
  display: none;
}
#img5{
  display: none;
}
#img6{
  display: none;
}
#img7{
  display: none;
}
#img8{
  display: none;
}
#img9{
  display: none;
}
#img10{
  display: none;
}
#img11{
  display: none;
}
#img12{
  display: none;
}
#img13{
  display: none;
}
#img14{
  display: none;
}
#img15{
  display: none;
}
#img16{
  display: none;
}
#img17{
  display: none;
}
#img18{
  display: none;
}
```

i am by no means an expert when it comes to jquery but i have looked around and cannot seem to find where i have gone wrong. It is most likely a basic mistake. I am attempting to make a gallery that will work with both images and youtube video and the only way i could think of to stop the video's autoplaying as soon as the page loaded was to use .add if there is a simpler more effective way of achieving this i would love to know as after scouring the internet i could not find a thing. Thank you in advance for any help that is given.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: the problem i am having is that the video does not load in at all

Comment: the video inside #v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not sure what you were trying to accomplish with the `for(true)` but taking that out and changing `add(...)` to `append(...)` gets your code to at least load the video, hope this helps. Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4n2my6za/

Comment: I was trying to make it run without stopping as once i have added the other images and videos it will carousel by itself until the page is closed thank you for your help and i will try an alternate method